# C# Event to check negative number in Circle

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have a simple C# program which should demonstrate the delegate and events concept.
But it it does not work as desired.
The Event checks only once the negative Number and then it finishes the program.
I want to see the 'Invalid Value' each time I enter a negative value.
Maybe Someone can tell me where the issue is.
*I am a C# beginner (please do not be so hard) :-)*

```
using System;

class Circle
{
    private double radius = 0;
    public double Radius
    {
        get { return radius; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                radius = value;
            else
                CircleEvent(this, new CircleEventArgs(value));
        }
    }

    public delegate void CircleEventHandler(object sender, CircleEventArgs args);
    public event CircleEventHandler CircleEvent;
}

class CircleEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public double Radius { get; set; }

    public CircleEventArgs(double radius)
    {
        Radius = radius;
    }
}

class Info
{
    public Info(Circle circle)
    {
        circle.CircleEvent += NewInput;
    }

    public void NewInput(object sender, CircleEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Value!");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        args.Radius = number;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        Info info = new Info(circle);
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        circle.Radius = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it should fire a message if I send a negative Number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the program to fire the event *every time* you enter a negative number, until you enter a valid number, you have to set the `Radius` property on the Circle instance. You're setting the `Radius` property on the CircleEventArgs, which does nothing as far as the Circle is concerned.

```
  public void NewInput(object sender, CircleEventArgs args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Value!");
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Circle c = sender as Circle;
    c.Radius = number;
    //args.Radius = number;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is via an Exception

[ArgumentException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ArgumentException is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one
>   of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of
>   the called method. The ParamName property identifies the invalid
>   argument.
>
> Most commonly, an ArgumentException is thrown by the common language
>   runtime or another class library and indicates developer error. If you
>   throw an ArgumentException from your code, you should ensure that the
>   exception's Message property includes a meaningful error message that
>   describes the invalid argument and the expected range of values for
>   the argument.

```
public double Radius
{
    get { return radius; }
    set
    {
        radius = value;
    }
}

public void DrawCircle()
{
    // this tells you a developer that the method is being misused
    if (radius <= 0 )
       throw new ArgumentExcetion("Radius cant be less or equal to 0");
    ...
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    Info info = new Info(circle);
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    circle.Radius = number;

    try
    {

    }
    catch(ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // log or alert the user
        // Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However because this is coming from user input you might also consider validate the input at a higher level. you could make a validation architecture, or you could just as easily and neatly validate at input

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    Info info = new Info(circle);
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while(number <= 0)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid input detected");
    }

    circle.Radius = number;

    try
    {

    }
    catch(ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // log or alert the user
        // Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```